# How to have both Velocity and Thymeleaf in the same project but have controllers using only one of them

Tags: spring-boot, velocity, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring boot with 2 separates templates engines : 
**Thymeleaf** : Used for **HTML rendering**
**Velocity** : Used for **emails formatting**
The application is working smoothly even though I get an **error in my logs mentioning a missing velocity template** (while I'm actually using the Thymeleaf one).
`Eg : ResourceManager : unable to find resource 'information-inquiry.vm' in any resource loader.`
My question was to find out if it was possible to have both engines plugged in but to disable velocity from trying to render templates from my controllers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting property `spring.velocity.enabled` to `false` should do the job - it disables creation of `VelocityViewResolver`, but keeps all the other Velocity related beans.

Always when you're trying to find out how to modify default Spring Boot behaviour I recommend to check Spring Boot sources and look for `*AutoConfiguration` classes, in this case `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.velocity.VelocityAutoConfiguration`.